# QGIS Server in HTTPS, redirecting HTTP

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-server

We have testing the set-up of a QGIS Server on a web-server in HTTPS. The GetCapabilities of the WFS service can be obtained with a HTTPS query, which works well and answer with the layers that we have stored.

However, when trying to add this layer in QGIS as a client, or any other GIS client, we got an error telling that the layer is not correct. I have identified that the GetFeature is requested with HTTP query, and not HTTPS: this may explain the issue.
On the GetCapabilities, I can read that the GET and POST URLs are indeed in HTTP only. Enclosed is a screenshot of the GetCapabilities.

Do you know how this parameter can be changed to HTTPS?

[image: QGis Server GetCapabilities WFS]

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities.

1. You can setup correct URL, with Https in properties in Qgis project.
2. From [Qgis 3.20](https://qgis.org/pl/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#id86) you can setup URL of services by header in proxy server.